# Android weird log behavior

Tags: android

I am performing some simple logging. Here is an example of a log statement:

```
Log.e("LogTag", "Inserted with ID: " + ret);
```

Here is what usually shows up:

```
06-12 12:54:12.890      963-963/com.example I/LogTag﹕ Inserted with ID: 1
```

But here is what sometimes shows up:

```
06-12 12:54:48.510      963-973/com.example E/LogTag﹕ [ 06-12 12:54:48.540   963:0x3c3 I/LogTag ]
    Inserted with ID: 102
```

As you can see, the log statement is somehow wrapped in an error log for some reason. What would cause this behavior?

Comment: Um, what is 'ret'? How is it calculated? Did you debug this?

Comment: It's a `long`. As you can see, it's showing up fine in both cases, but one case has the statement wrapped completely in an error log.

Comment: Show your logging code.

Comment: I did. It's the first code snippet in my question.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to say. But this looks to me like a timing issue, possibly two threads trying to log something at once. The documentation doesn't say if `Log` is thread-safe. I would suggest synchronizing your own code by using a lock object.